# Render_activity in a Bootstrap dropdown menu isn't working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, public-activity

So I am doing this in a Bootstrap dropdown menu in a partial in my main layout:

```
      <% @unread_act.each do |notification| %>
        <li>
    <%= render_activity notification %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
```

`@unread_act` is declared in my `application_controller.rb` like so:

```
  @unread_act = Notification.where(recipient_id: current_user).includes(:trackable => [:user, :node]).order("created_at desc")
```

Then in my `views/public_activity/comment/_create.html.erb`, I have this:

added a comment to 

  which has since been removed

The issue is that in the dropdown menu, it doesn't display this info. It literally just displays what would be the equivalent of:

`activity.trackable.node.name`

No idea where it is getting that information, but that's what it is doing.

Any ideas on how I can customize this dropdown menu for my needs?

Also as an aside, I have no idea why the dropdown passes `notification` to `render_activity`, but the gem still wants `activity.trackable`. I tried `notification.trackable` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my Dropdown menu, based on Bootstrap:

```
<div class="notifications bootstrap-styles">
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#"><%= @unread_act.size %></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <% @unread_act.each do |notification| %>
            <li>
                            <%= render_activity notification %>
                        </li>
          <% end %>

         <li><%= link_to "Mark all as read", mark_all_read_activities_path, method: :put %></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What was happening is that this Dropdown menu will only display links.

So it is only the elements within a `link_to` tag that get shown in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, sir. According to [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns), is used to display links only. What if you change your `render_activity` helper to include a link? Something like this may work for you:

```
def render_activity(notification)
  link_to notification, nil
end
```